# Save style to DB (PostgreSQL) - QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, style, database

When trying to save a style to PostGIS database through QGIS I am getting the error:

> Unable to save layer style. It's not possible to insert a new record into the style table. Maybe this is due to table permissions (user=admin_gis). Please contact your database administrator.

After reading other posts, I have found there is no layer_styles in the public schema. I have tried adding this table in manually and re-saving but still receiving the same error.

I cant seem to find a resolution that works for me online, has anyone else had/solved this problem?

[image]

Comment: Is `public` part of admin_gis search path? (connect to Postgres as admin_gis and type `SHOW search_path;` )

Comment: Yes I get the output:  "$user",public

Answer (score 4):

Solved using different syntax:

> CREATE TABLE layer_styles( 
>     id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY 
>     ,f_table_catalog varchar 
>     ,f_table_schema varchar 
>     ,f_table_name varchar 
>     ,f_geometry_column varchar 
>     ,styleName varchar(30) 
>     ,styleQML xml 
>     ,styleSLD xml 
>     ,useAsDefault boolean 
>     ,description text 
>     ,owner varchar(30) 
>     ,ui xml 
>     ,update_time timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
>   )